# How to link two tables but only take the MAX value from one table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgres-9.6

I have two tables

```
exchange_rates
TIMESTAMP             curr1    curr2    rate
2018-04-01 00:00:00   EUR      GBP      0.89
2018-04-01 01:30:00   EUR      GBP      0.92
2018-04-01 01:20:00   USD      GBP      1.23
```

and

```
transactions
TIMESTAMP             user    curr    amount
2018-04-01 18:00:00   1       EUR     23.12
2018-04-01 14:00:00   1       USD     15.00
2018-04-01 01:00:00   2       EUR     55.00
```

I want to link these two tables on 1. currency and 2. TIMESTAMP in the following way:

- `curr` in `transactions` must be equal to `curr1` in `exchange_rates`
- `TIMESTAMP` in `exchange_rates` must be less than or equal to `TIMESTAMP` in `transactions` (so we only pick up the exchange rate that was relevant at the time of transaction)

I have this:

```
SELECT
trans.TIMESTAMP, trans.user,
-- Multiply the amount in transactions by the corresponding rate in exchange_rates
trans.amount * er.rate AS "Converted Amount"
FROM transactions trans, exchange_rates er
WHERE trans.curr = er.curr1
AND er.TIMESTAMP <= trans.TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY trans.user
```

but this is linking on two many results as the output is more rows than there are in `transactions`.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
TIMESTAMP             user    Converted Amount
2018-04-01 18:00:00   1       21.27
2018-04-01 14:00:00   1       18.45
2018-04-01 01:00:00   2       48.95
```

The logic behind the `Converted Amount`:

- row 1: user spent at 18:00 so take the `rate` that is less than or equal to the `TIMESTAMP` in `exchange_rates` i.e. 0.92 for EUR at 01:30
- row 2: user spent at 14:00 so take the `rate` that is less than or equal to the `TIMESTAMP` in `exchange_rates` i.e. 1.23 for USD at 01:20
- row 3: user spent at 01:00 so take the `rate` that is less than or equal to the `TIMESTAMP` in `exchange_rates` i.e. 0.89 for EUR at 00:00

**How can I do this in postgresql 9.6**?

Comment: Please tag your Postgres version.

Comment: I edited the question - its version 9.6

Comment: I don't have much time at the moment. So here are some options: **(1)** Use `DISTINCT ON` to reduce your result set. **(2)** Use a subquery in the `SELECT` clause. **(3)** Use a `LATERAL` join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [LATERAL JOIN](https://medium.com/kkempin/postgresqls-lateral-join-bfd6bd0199df) (CROSS APPLY) and limit the result to the first row that match your conditions.

> ```
> select t.dt, t.usr, t.amount * e.rate as conv_amount
> from   transactions t
> join lateral (select *
>               from   exchange_rates er
>               where  t.curr = er.curr1
>               and    er.dt <= t.dt
>               order by dt desc
>               limit 1) e on true;
> ```
>
> ```
> dt                  | usr | conv_amount
> :------------------ | --: | ----------:
> 2018-04-01 18:00:00 |   1 |     21.2704
> 2018-04-01 14:00:00 |   1 |     18.4500
> 2018-04-01 01:00:00 |   2 |     48.9500
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0ca0454be556c6b3f0d5d63c78486837)*

Comment: This would be my preferred way, too.